# Filtering results of an SOQL query

Tags: apex, soql, dynamic-soql

I have a SOQL query with a lot of filters and I want to group the results and process objects which match a certain filter. For eg. I could have a query where I want to process different kind of leads differently,

```
List<Lead> leads = [Select id,name,ownerId from Lead where rating = 'Hot' or leadsource='Web' or name like 'Sam%'];
```

For rating = 'Hot' , I want to change the ownerId to 'X'.

For leadSource ='Web', I want to change the ownerId to 'Y'

For name like 'Sam%', I want to change to a queue

I can think of 2 ways of doing this -

1) To have different queries for individual filters and process the objects

2) Or to loop over the results and have an if/else statement to identify the action

Is there any other way to optimize it? Can I group the results based on filters?

Comment: Option 2 with if else is better.

Answer (score 0):

Lead assigment rules not be the best in your situation?

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=creating_assignment_rules.htm&type=5

Comment: No, want to do it using apex since there is a lot of other processing also happening on the results.

Comment: One does not exclude the other in my opinion.